# Sudden Mail Error

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, debian, dovecot

Today, after working for ages, my mailing stopped working.

Zend Framework returned an error

```
Message: Could not read from localhost
```

After searching on the web, I relaised it came from Dovecot, on my Debian machine.

Looking at the logs, it said:

```
server1 postfix/smtpd[15194]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

And I couldn't find what was working wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some unlucky try, I decided to restart dovecot, which said:

```
    Restarting IMAP/POP3 mail server: dovecotLast died with error 
(see error log for more information): Time just moved backwards by 899 seconds. 
This might cause a lot of problems, so I'll just kill myself now. 
http://wiki.dovecot.org/TimeMovedBackwards
```

Which made me realise that I installed ntp because I had some problem with time synchronisation and it got the time back from more than 10 mn, which seem to give a hard time to dovecot.

So if that happen to someone, don't look for way to fix a SASL authentication, just try to restart your dovecot.

Since there is not once a mention of this problem I could find on the web, I hope this one will help people.